# Doctrine equivalent for Sql with if condition

Tags: doctrine-orm

Could anyone please let me know the Doctrine equivalent for the below query.

SELECT if(chat_user_one = '$user_id', chat_user_two, chat_user_one) AS uid FROM tbl_chats WHERE chat_id='$c_id'

I tried using:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select("c.chatId")
                ->addSelect("IF(c.chatUserOne = '$userId', c.chatUserTwo,    c.chatUserOne)")

                ->from("TblChats", "c")
                ->where('c.chatId = ?1')
                ->setParameter(1, $cId);*/

$query = $qb->getQuery();         
$result = $query->getResult();
```

But failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine's query language does not appear to support the `IF` conditional flow syntax, however, you may be able to use `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ...` to achieve what you want.

Try writing your select as:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select("c.chatId")
       ->addSelect("CASE WHEN c.chatUserOne = '$userId' THEN c.chatUserTwo ELSE c.chatUserOne END")
...
```

Doctrine discusses, to a certain extent its support for `CASE` operations, [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#case-expressions).